# how to get also 0 from the string (Regular expression)

Tags: regex

how to get also 0 from this string, this is how I try,/thanks

`[^\s\/][\w\s]+[^\s\/]`

```
....text..text./..text.text.text...../.0....... (dots = spaces)
```

https://regex101.com/r/FeXsEH/1

i need array, without '/' and ' all spaces':

```
text text
text text text
0
```

Comment: Do you want to match the text parts in groups separated by the /, and the 0 also?

Comment: Yes, parts separated by the / and spaces

Comment: Hi @Sedler, I think we have an answer worked for your case now. please have a try. in short, instead of specifying the seperator pattern, you can directly specify the extracted text pattern to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

***This was quite a hard and interesting one:***

```
(?!\s)[\w\s]+(?<!\s)
```

***Explanation:***

- **(?!\s)** If it doesn't have space in front, continue with the step below
- **[\w\s]*** match as many alphanumeric characters and spaces.
- **(?<!\s)** and match nothing if it doesn't have space before, meaning it has a alphanumeric character, therefore ending the match right there and not capture any extra spaces.

Comment: your example gives 4 matches, but I need 3 matches so instead of * I used +
(?!\s)[\w\s]+(?<!\s)
Thank you!

Comment: It displays more matches in regex101, but if you use it on a actual environment, like in python that I tested it, it works fine, but good tweak you did!

Comment: Hi @RifloSnake, your example gives 4 matches if there are no more spaces at the end of the phrase or 0. I need 3 matches so instead of * I used +
`(?!\s)[\w\s]+(?<!\s)`
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can also describe the expetected extraction as:
start with word characters with one single padding space, keep repeated pattern and then the last word without padding space.

The above can translated into the following regex:

```
(\w+\s)*\w+
```

Output in [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/EiMtKE/1):

```
text text
text text text
0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match 1 or more word characters, and then optionally repeat 1 or more whitespace characters followed by again 1 or more word characters:

```
\w+(?:\s+\w+)*
```

**Explanation**

- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\s+\w+` Match 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ word chars
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1uZEnK/1).